# CSS Bootstrap: an horizontal scrollbar appears

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying Bootstrap on a small project, But there is something I don't understand or I should do wrong. Here is my snippet:

```css
nav{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
section{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <header class="page-header"></header>
  <div id="mainContainer" class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Menu item 1</li>
        <li>Menu item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
      Here is my content.
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

An horizontal scroll bar appears, how can I properly fix it, ***without adding external css rule***, using only Bootstrap ones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a use `.container` for a responsive fixed width **[Container](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)**. Add this class to your `div`

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="row container">
```

[image]

- Use `.container` for a responsive fixed width container.
- Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you forgot your container.

```css
nav{ background-color: lightblue; } section{ background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <header class="page-header"></header>
  <div class="container">
  <div id="mainContainer" class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Menu item 1</li>
        <li>Menu item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
      Here is my content.
    </section>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a full-width layout, so container-fluid is more appropriate (Rajshekar Reddy's answer).

Comment: "I believe you forgot your container."  -- exactly. And Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the container class within your HTML markup, it needs to be:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is your code with the container class added:

```css
nav{ background-color: lightblue; } section{ background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
   <header class="page-header"></header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="mainContainer" class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
           <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
              <li>Home</li>
              <li>Menu item 1</li>
              <li>Menu item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
       <section class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
         Here is my content.
       </section>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a full-width layout, so `container-fluid` is more appropriate (Rajshekar Reddy's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class 'row' form :

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="row">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper around the .row with the .overflow-hidden class:

```
<div class="container overflow-hidden">
```